# Arabic Language in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development

I have installed Arabic Language Pack for Sharepoint Server 2013 and my site is converted to arabic language but the issue is my content and metadata which i typed is not translating in arabic. any body know that how to change this in to arabic?

Answer (score 0):

After you have installed a language pack, you have to do some work in the Managed metadata service where you want your terms to be in Arabic.

Navigate to the Managed Metadata service through Central Admin with your farm account and on the first view you should be able to pick your newly installed language pack under Working languages. Here you can change the default language so that Arabic terms will be shown as default and it's here you have to add Arabic as a working language.

However take note that adding a new working language from a language pack is a resource consuming job. Do it after-work hours.

> "If you add a new working language to a term store, do so during a period when your SharePoint site is not heavily used, such as at night. When you add a new working language, a timer job updates each site collection’s cache and adds the text to display in the new language to every term in the cache. This may affect performance temporarily."

[image]

See this site for more information: [Work with multi-lingual term sets](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Work-with-multi-lingual-term-sets-d04098af-282b-45c3-97cb-59363042c1b3) It's for SharePoint 2010 but the procedure is pretty much the same.

[Plan for the multilingual user interface in SharePoint 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff805087.aspx)